# Damaged passport

Tags: passports, indian-citizens

My passport got little damaged by water though every thing is clearly visible. Can this create any problem in future? Anyone please help.

Comment: See https://portal1.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqLostDamagedPassports

Answer (score 1):

From the given pictures, the details are intact for those pages. Unless any unreadable details, it should not be any issue.

But for safer side, you can easily renew passport within few days if you are still staying the same passport address.

(The images have now been removed for the asker's privacy. They showed some smudging of a stamp and a little staining of the ID pages but everything was clearly legible.)